# Concatenate string vector which is element of the list

Tags: r, list, sapply, mapply

I need to concatenate strings, that are nested in a list. String vectors are of different length, so transforming into data frame is not an option.

List looks as follows:

```
x <- list( a = letters[1:3], b = LETTERS[4:9])

> x
$a
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$b
[1] "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I"
```

Desired output:

```
[1] "a_b_c" "D_E_F_G_H_I"
```

I thought of using `sapply`, but at least the following doesn't work:

```
sapply(x, function(z) paste(z, '_'))
```

Moreover, it produces super weird whitespaces (well, obviously, I don't get how `sapply` works.

Comment: have you tried, `paste0(z, collapse="_")`?

Comment: gives ` "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")_c(\"D\", \"E\", \"F\", \"G\", \"H\", \"I\")"`. Not really what I want...

Comment: I think he meant in the `sapply` call : `sapply(x, function(z) paste0(z, collapse='_'))`

Comment: OK. I'll keep the comment for newbies like myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not providing an argument to `collapse`:

```
sapply(x, function(z) paste(z, collapse='_'))
            a             b 
      "a_b_c" "D_E_F_G_H_I"
```

Even better would be to simply use it as an argument in `sapply`. You don't need a separator, so I suggest `paste0`, which has `""` by default:

```
sapply(x, paste0, collapse='_')
```

Comment: No need to define a function, argument can be passed  in sapply directly: `sapply(x, paste, collapse='_')`

Comment: This is also true, I was attempting to show how close to the answer OP was. I've been really hasty on this one...